# Which data storage and retrieval strategy is more performant in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm creating an app with Mongo, Express, and Node.js. The app customizes models/descriptions of combat vehicles for tabletop war gaming (miniatures combat).

Each vehicle has several properties, such as body type, power source, etc. There are about half a dozen such properties. The options available for each property are in most cases less than a dozen. While some of the options will have several data points (cost, weight, size, name, etc) the descriptions of these options will not change frequently, if at all. In addition, while it is possible new options will be added, this will be infrequent.

In other words, most of the data will be static.

User data (what vehicles the user has designed, etc) and descriptions of vehicles will be stored in a mongo database, as these are changeable and frequently expanded.

However, would it make more sense to put some of this other information in as constants in the API programming? A list of values for component positions is a simple array (top, bottom, front, back, left right) so that's easy to do. But what about Body Type, where there are 13 options, each of which has 6 properties (name, type, cost, weight, etc). Is it more performant to simply put something like this in a JSON file retrieved as needed? Or to put it in a database?

Again, the data is (pretty much) static, so maintenance isn't a major concern. Memory usage, and possibly network bandwidth, are.

In the case of a JSON file, the API (or UI, depending on the scenario) would need to use filtering functions I  write to pick out the applicable records, though iterating over a 13-entry array doesn't seem that intensive. Meanwhile, if I store it in Mongo I will only ever be looking at data that has already been filtered. Will calling Mongo up be faster and/or less resource intensive than opening a plain text file?

Is there a rough threshold for this? There are over 2 dozen weapons, some of which have variations.

So, am I better off just making a JSON file or putting it in a Mongo collection? or does it not matter and maybe I'm focusing this as a way to procrastinate getting code written?

Answer (score 0):

Try and look at it from a `maintainability` and `extensibility` points of view.

- Will you need to re-deploy to make changes?
- How many network calls will you make anyway?
- Will "hardcoding" some values make your flow tangled?
- What about sharing the data between hosts, is it an issue?

To me it feels you should store your data in some datastore (mongo).